Take Screenshot/snapshot from .ts file
I need to take a screenshot/snapshot from .ts files.
Currently using the command:
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:05.6710000 -i input.ts -frames:v 1 -q:v 1 output.jpeg
This works fine for .mp4 files, but for .ts files the output file is just garbage.
I've tried different values for -frames:v 1 and -q:v 1, but same result.
Note, ffmpeg will convert .ts to mp4, so I'm guessing it's a question of correct parameters, however all my searches have been fruitless.
Command output is:

ffmpeg version 7.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers

built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static
--disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint
libavutil      59.  8.100 / 59.  8.100
libavcodec     61.  3.100 / 61.  3.100
libavformat    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavdevice    61.  1.100 / 61.  1.100
libavfilter    10.  1.100 / 10.  1.100
libswscale      8.  1.100 /  8.  1.100
libswresample   5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libpostproc    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
[mpegts @ 0000020349fd7a00] Could not find codec parameters for stream
1 (Unknown: none ([164][0][0][0] / 0x00A4)): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and
'probesize' (5000000) options
Input #0, mpegts, from 'input.ts':
Duration: 00:12:02.03, start: 8961.200000, bitrate: 1560 kb/s
Program 1
Stream #0:0[0xa5]: Video: hevc (Main) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024),
yuv420p(tv), 2688x1520, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream #0:1[0xa4]: Unknown: none ([164][0][0][0] / 0x00A4)
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> mjpeg (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[hevc @ 000002034a5d0540] Could not find ref with POC 49
[swscaler @ 00000203512ce040] deprecated pixel format used, make sure
you did set range correctly
Output #0, image2, to 'output.jpeg':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf61.1.100

Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, progressive), 2688x1520,
q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn
  Metadata:

    encoder         : Lavc61.3.100 mjpeg

  Side data:

    cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A

[image2 @ 000002034a5ce5c0] The specified filename 'output.jpeg' does
not contain an image sequence pattern or a pattern is invalid.
[image2 @ 000002034a5ce5c0] Use a pattern such as %03d for an image
sequence or use the -update option (with -frames:v 1 if needed) to
write a  single image.
[out#0/image2 @ 000002034a4d3140] video:73KiB audio:0KiB subtitle:0KiB
other streams:0KiB global headers:0KiB muxing overhead: unknown
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A dup=1
drop=0 speed=0.317x

How can I create the snapshot?

Can you convert THIS .ts file into .mp4 successfully? Just to check if there are issues with the .ts file itself.

Yes, I can convert .ts to mp4 successfully with ffmpeg.

I think that it might be a bug related to H.265 (HEVC) video codec used with .ts files. Place the -ss after the -i (also add -update 1): ffmpeg -y -i input.ts -ss 00:06:05.6710000 -frames:v 1 -update 1 -q:v 1 output.jpeg. Note that converting to MP4 with -c copy (ffmpeg -y -i input.ts -c copy input.mp4) and using -ss before the -i can be faster if -ss value is large.

Thanks @Rotem. Placing -ss after -i works, but takes too long. Depending on the -ss value, it can take several minutes, which will not be acceptable. -update doesn't seem to do anything. Any other ideas?

While I can imply that you are successfully converting THIS .ts file, my question was precise because in diagnostics we need precision. Perhaps there is a language issue, but please note that we are asking whether THIS .ts file can be successfully and correctly converted to an mp4 file. I recommend that you use precise language, especially when precision is requested.

Thanks for the reply @music2myear. My only language issue may be with video terminology. I took 'THIS' to mean the same file that I'm trying to take a snapshot of. If it means something else, please explain. 'Successfully and correctly converted', I take to mean that the resulting mp4 file can be viewed in Windows Media Player. If it means something else, please explain, as video files and video processing are not my forte. I'm just trying to do something that I thought would be (and is for mp4) a simple task.

Your answer "I can convert .ts to mp4" means you can convert A .ts file. My question is whether you were able to convert the specific .ts file in question, the one you're trying to pull these screenshots from. If you are able to convert the .ts files you are unable to pull screenshots from, you could specify that by saying "I can convert these same .ts files successfully, so I am pretty sure the issue is not with the .ts files." or something similar.

Thanks for the clarification @music2myear. Yes, I can convert the specific file to mp4, as well as any others from the same source. Once converted, I can create a snapshot from any of the mp4's. I hope this clarifies things.
Note in my response to Rotem, if I move the -ss parameter after -i, taking the screenshot works, however, it is very slow. Does that possibly point to another solution?

My other solution is converting the .ts to MP4 using -c copy, and then using -ss before the -i. Since it is not working due to a bug in FFmpeg, I don't think there is some magical solution...

Thanks @Rotem. That was my initial thought also, but conversion takes too long.

You may try to file a bug report (note that I never tried that). For reproducing the issue we may create a synthetic video using FFmpeg: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=2688x1520:rate=30:duration=10 -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuvj420p input.ts, then extract a frame as JPEG image: ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05.6710000 -i input.ts -frames:v 1 -update 1 -q:v 1 output.jpeg. The output image is gray.

Thanks @Rotem. I can't wait for a bug fix. I've found a workaround. I convert a 2 second slice of the .ts to .mp4, then take the snapshot from that. It's a bit crude, but keeps me moving forward. If anyone has a better idea, I'm open.

Good idea! just make sure you are getting the correct frame. The following example extracts the wrong frame: ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05.6710000 -i input.ts -frames:v 1 -c copy tmp.mp4 and ffmpeg -y -i tmp.mp4 -update 1 output.jpeg (I am getting the number 8 instead of 5 with the testsrc input).

We may better test it using sequence of numbered frames at 30fps: ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -r 30 -i testsrc=size=2688x1520:rate=1:duration=300 -vf setpts=N/30/TB -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuvj420p input.ts and ffmpeg -y -i input.ts -ss 00:00:05.6710000 -frames:v 1 -update 1 -q:v 1 output1.jpeg, compared to: ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:05.6710000 -i input.ts -frames:v 1 -c copy tmp.mp4 and ffmpeg -y -i tmp.mp4 -update 1 output2.jpeg.

Thanks @Rotem. I've tested my method with several files and looks good. But, I'll play with your suggestions also.
